# "Sitefinity Renderer Layout was created successfully" prompts but files are not added in project - [Sitefinity]

Tags: asp.net, command-line-interface, sitefinity, sitefinity-10, sitefinity-5

I am working with Sitefinity. Trying to create a layout file with dotnet CLI,
The tutorial shows the following command

`dotnet new sitefinity-layout --layout-name '_testLayout'`

I entered this in the Package Manager CLI, the prompts show as Success.
Result :

> The template "Sitefinity Renderer Layout" was created successfully

[image]

But there are no files added to the solution.
The following is my solution explorer image.

[image]